# How do I change the order (ASC and DESC) in the following retrieval method using WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query

The following code retrieves only custom post types with the custom taxonomy "Slider."

I would like to change their order to ASC.

The  code:

```
<?php // Retrive custom post type with a custom taxonomy assigned to it
 $posts = new WP_Query('post_type=page_content&page_sections=Slider (Front Page)') ?>
 <?php while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
 <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Not sure if I should use an array (not sure how anyways).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change this line in your code:

```
 $posts = new WP_Query('post_type=page_content&page_sections=Slider (Front Page)') ?>
```

to this:

```
 $posts = new WP_Query('post_type=page_content&page_sections=Slider (Front Page)&order=ASC') ?>
```

Basically it adds the order parameter witch can take two values (ASC,DESC).

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Which order you want to achieve? Chronological? Alphabetical?

In any case see [Order & Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) in Codex for available arguments.